# Discord.client is not a constructor - discord.js

Tags: node.js, npm, discord, discord.js, termux

I made a Discord bot and tried beginner code I found on YouTube. This is my code and my errors:

#### File *index.js*

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.client();
const config = require('./config.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('the client is ready!')
})

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(config.token)
```

#### Errors

```
~/.../stuff/hazy $ node hazy.js
/storage/emulated/0/stuff/hazy/hazy.js:3
const client = new Discord.client();
               ^

TypeError: Discord.client is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/storage/emulated/0/stuff/hazy/hazy.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) class provided by [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) is called **Client**.

> Client
>
> Client extends BaseClient
>
> The main hub for interacting with the
> Discord API, and the starting point for any bot.

Use `new Discord.Client()` instead of `new Discord.client()`.

Or directly import the client using
`const { Discord, Client } = require("discord.js")`
and then instantiate with `new Client()`

Comment: thanks, it was my spelling mistake all the time, your answer really helped me alot.